# Jquery selectors optimization

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

Consider the html

```
<div id="one" >
<input type="radio" value="x" name="group" >
<input type="radio" value="y" name="group" >
<input type="radio" value="z" name="group" >
</div>
```

I have two questions regarding the DOM access with Jquery.

1. **Question One**

I just want to find the value of input radio which is selected.So i have

Method 1:

```
var value="";
$("#one input:radio[name=group]").each(function(){
  if($(this).is(:checked)){
   value=$(this).val();
  }
});
```

Method 2:

```
var value=$("#one input:radio[name=group]:checked").val();
```

is there a considerable performance difference in between two methods ? rather than method 2 do that in one line of code..

Or please explain actually what is happening with the line `"input:radio[name=group]:checked"` inside jquery?

1. **Question Two**

I want to set the checked attribute true 
to input having value "y". So

```
$("input:radio").filter("[value=y]").attr('checked', true);
```

and

```
$("#one input:radio[name=group]").filter("[value=y]").attr('checked', true);
```

will do the same .

Is there any performance difference in adding "div id" and  "[name=group]" ?

Comment: document.getElementById is the fastest one!!

Comment: "is there a considerable performance difference in between two methods ? rather than method 2 do that in one line of code.." Doing things in one line of code has nothing to do with performance *per se*.

Comment: yes .. i mean that itself,the only advantage is saving line of code ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it comes down to pure perf, there is one solution I find better: "Do it yourself" (on [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/) )

I did your test, but it only took me the time to make a copy/paste `;)`

http://jsperf.com/selectoroptimization

From the result I add, the best method seems to be the second one for the first question but for the second one it depends on the browser.

Comment: ok thanks for "jsperf" .. do find any explanation for actually what is happening inside JQuery.?

Comment: Nope, I'm not that familiar with what's happening inside jQuery.

Comment: Py: awesome! I didn't know about jsperf !